# <p> tag different font-size on mobile without any css

Tags: html, css

[image: HTML display on chromium debug mode]

As you can see from above, I have an assortment of html tags. Absolutely no CSS is being used, just the user agent.

This page behaves normally when not in a mobile device. The font size of `<p>` tags grows greatly when I'm viewing it through a mobile device. I've discovered no documentation on this.

Obviously the `<p>` tag is grown in size to be more mobile-friendly without any css intervention. This is clearly a crappy "bug-feature" as the tables and inputs are microscopic. Is this normal behavior? How do I mimic the effect of what's happening to the `<p>` tag?

Comment: @Xufox good point. edited.

Comment: Does adding `html{-ms-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-size-adjust: none;}` to your CSS change this behavior?

Comment: @user6003859 Ah yes it does. Go ahead and put that in answer form and you got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove this behavior, you can use the following CSS:

```
html
{
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

This instructs (especially mobile-)browsers to not adjust the size of your text automatically.